# ¿Cómo llegó el coloquialismo "hacer el caldo gordo" a tener su significado actual?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones, coloquialismos, españa

Leyendo hoy la prensa española, me he encontrado con [esta noticia](http://www.expansion.com/mercados/2018/08/29/5b86609a46163f26598b4578.html) en el Expansión. En uno de los comentarios  alguien dice

> Morgan le está haciendo el **caldo gordo** a los bajistas, muchos de ellos atrapados en precios entorno a los 24 ​/ 25 euros.

Según el DRAE, "[hacer el caldo gordo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6lMDpXZ)" es una locución adverbial coloquial que quier decir "seguirle o hacerle el juego" a alguien.

Esto significaría que ese comentarista piensa que el banco Morgan Stanley le hace el juego a aquellos inversores (los bajistas<sup>1</sup>) que apuestan por que la empresa bajará mucho en bolsa.

¿Cómo llegó el coloquialismo "**hacer el caldo gordo**" a tener su significado actual?

---

1- Los *bajistas*, por si alguien se hace la pregunta, son un tipo de inversores que apuestan por que la cotización de una empresa va a bajar. Piden entonces prestados títulos de esa empresa para vender. Venden hoy a X y pagan los los títulos a su propietario en una fecha futura, esperando tener que pagar menos que ese precio X por el que vendieron las acciones de la empresa.

Comment: En [este artículo](https://www.taringa.net/posts/info/1636864/El-origen-de-frases-que-siempre-usamos.html) lo mencionan como aquel caldo con mucha _chicha_, a diferencia del aguachirle. Hacer el caldo gordo a alguien sería, literalmente, prepararle una comida nutritiva, que le haría bien.

Comment: @fedorqui curioso que en el artículo que enlazas se diga que "el caldo gordo es un plato imaginario", cuando hay tratados gastronómicos del siglo XVI que hablan de "caldo gordo", que no es más que un "caldo graso".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La explicación es simple: un caldo gordo es un caldo con grasa, con sustancia. Fíjate en la definición de *gordo* de Covarrubias (1611):

> Lo gruesso y mantecoso de la carne del animal.

Tienes usos literales de *caldo gordo* ya en el siglo XVI:

> *[...] y sobre la vaca cortada y hechos platos de ella sembrar sal con un cuchillo y echar del mismo caldo sobre la carne; si la carne es magra, sea el caldo gordo; si fuere la carne gorda, echarle el caldo magro, que no tenga gordura; [...].*
>
> Anónimo, "Libro de guisados de Ruperto de Nola", 1529 (España).

Esta idea de "caldo con sustancia" empezó a tener sentidos figurados, como este del siglo XVIII:

> *Poco importa que a este género de conducta vil, llamen los discretos ignominia de la naturaleza racional. Eso no lo saben los mentecatos; y sólo con estos se ha de hacer el caldo gordo de nuestra fortuna.*
>
> Fray Martín Sarmiento, "El porque sí y porque no", a1772 (España).

No es el mismo sentido que el que buscas, pero ya nos da a entender que un *caldo gordo* se puede asociar a abundancia, como en otra frase que he leído: "a tener dinero, que es quien hace el caldo gordo". El siguiente paso ya es asociar el *hacerle un caldo gordo a alguien* con "darle todo lo que quiere". Esto se empieza a ver en el siglo XIX:

> *La Constitución, tal cual es, nos ha de hacer sudar a los que queremos echarla abajo; pero si, por purísima ignorancia, nos ayudan a destruirla los mismos que la sostienen, nos hacen el caldo gordo y les debemos estar muy agradecidos.*
>
> Sebastián de Miñano, "Sátiras y panfletos del Trienio Constitucional", 1820-1823 (España).

O este de la hemeroteca, ligeramente anterior:

> *Esta plaza [de Censor de los Diarios de Madrid] no ha tenido jamás dotacion fixa, pero los gages, y emolumentos que rinde de maldiciones, amenazas, rencores y acusaciones de los censurados, son capaces de hacer el caldo gordo á qualquier pobre diablo.*
>
> Diario de Madrid. 2/5/1800, página 1.

Estos usos son ya semejantes al que se le da en la actualidad.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando lo indicado por la correctísima [respuesta de Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27255/1674), creo interesante mostrar lo que describe el artículo [*El origen de frases que siempre usamos*](https://www.taringa.net/posts/info/1636864/El-origen-de-frases-que-siempre-usamos.html) de Taringa!:

> **Hacer el caldo gordo**
>
> Dicho popular que se utiliza con el significado de adular, ayudar o favorecer a alguien con el fin de obtener algún beneficio. El “caldo gordo” es un plato imaginario, no existen recetas que sirvan para prepararlo, aunque su contenido sería diverso y variado, con verduras y carnes de todo tipo. El caldo, sustancia reconstituyente, era en otro tiempo alimento para trabajadores a domicilio, viajeros y menesterosos que necesitaban un sustancioso aporte de calorías. Por lo que se sabe, el significado de “caldo gordo” sería lo contrario que el aguachirle, insustante por naturaleza, sin apenas calorías en su contenido alimenticio. Con el caldo gordo se agasajaba a personajes de importancia y el aguachirle se reservaba para los que no podían pagar o andaban escasos de recursos económicos.

Por tanto, hacer el caldo gordo a alguien sería, literalmente, prepararle una comida nutritiva que le haría bien.

Charlie [objetó](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27244/c%C3%B3mo-lleg%C3%B3-el-coloquialismo-hacer-el-caldo-gordo-a-tener-su-significado-actua/27255#comment45767_27244) que lo de "el caldo gordo es un plato imaginario" no es del todo correcto, indicando que hay tratados gastronómicos del siglo XVI que hablan de "caldo gordo", que no es más que un "caldo graso". Por tanto, sea o no sea imaginario, un caldo así en esencia es un caldo "potente".

Comment: Curioso lo de "[aguachirle](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1BnOWK5)", por aquí decimos "aguachirri".

Comment: @Charlie sí, por aquí también, aunque tiene más sentido lo de [_chirle_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8sNEAYH) que chirri, que aquí es muy vulgar para vagina. Curiosamente, de etimología similar también existen [_aguachile_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1Bk3YKE), [_aguachinoso_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1BmayFk) y [_aguachinar_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1BlxZto).